# Writing twosum in a static way

Tags: java, static

Can someone help me with this code?

```
class Solutiontest1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(twoSum(scan.nextLine()).split(" "),scan.nextInt() );
    
            
}

public int[] static twoSum(new int[], int){
    int[] result = new int[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < str_arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < str_arr.length; j++) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(str_arr[i]) + Integer.parseInt(str_arr[j]) == target) {
                result[0] = i;
                result[1] = j;

            }
        }
    }
    return reult;
}

}
```

I need to write twoSum in a static way. I receive error"The method twoSum(String) is undefined for the type Solutiontest1"!
Thanks

Comment: Read the error message carefully. Tell us exactly what you think it means.

Comment: @tgdavies  This question was flagged. As I'm reviewing it for deletion, I'm wondering if I should just keep it, or whether I should delete it for the `public int[] static`, the many issues with the code, the formatting... or should I delete this post because the question is clearly, concisely, and perfectly answered by the simple error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have typos, invalid syntax, an incorrect method signature and code that parses strings to ints many many times. Let's start with the method signature, you are trying to pass a `String[]` and an `int` target. Not an `int[]`, and that method returns an `int[]` which means you can't print it directly to get the values (because `int[]` doesn't override `Object.toString()`). So, to call your method, do something like

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(twoSum(scan.nextLine().split("\\s*"),
        scan.nextInt())));
```

That will split on (and consume optional) whitespace. And print the results using `Arrays.toString(int[])`. Then your method can be improved by first converting the `String[]` to an `int[]` and then comparing the sums. Like,

```
public static int[] twoSum(String[] str_arr, int target) {
    int[] arr = Arrays.stream(str_arr).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
    int[] result = new int[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[i] + arr[j] == target) {
                result[0] = i;
                result[1] = j;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```